# How to print column name inside function applied to all columns with dplyr 0.8.1

Tags: r, dplyr

I had a working function under previous version of `dplyr` (0.8.0.1), but now it prints dots instead of the column name.

The print is merely a dummy approach. In my real code I print the column name in a `sweetalert` message that keeps the user of my `R Shiny app` updated on progress of a long calculation. The dummy code here is part of a more extensive `dplyr` code

Perhaps there is a bug in the new `dplyr`, but if anyone knows how to achieve retrieving the column names inside the function while sticking to `dplyr` approach, i'd be glad to hear it.

I have tried with clean sessions, loading only `dplyr` and `multimode`, and the behavior changes with the version of `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) # version 0.8.1 vs 0.8.0.1 used here
library(multimode)
funx <- function(x) {
    print(substitute(x))
    multires <- multimode::modetest(x, method = 'SI') 
    p <- multires$p.value}

mtcars %>% 
    select(1:2) %>%
    summarise_all(list(~ funx(.)))
```

Comment: An option would be `funx <- function(x, y) {
print(y);
multires <- multimode::modetest(x, method = 'SI');
multires$p.value
}; mtcars %>% select(2, 3) %>% imap(funx)`

Comment: hm yes that works... then I need to figure out now how to merge the imap output into 1 dataframe in the pipeline

Comment: In that case `%>% enframe %>% unnest`

Comment: sorry for driving you nuts akrun. Seems for some reason rename doesn't work either in this structure. I tried to pipe it in at different places but I  keep getting Error in rename(., Parameter = name) : unused argument (Parameter = name)

Comment: May be another change in other package versions.  It is working fine for me `mtcars %>% select(2, 3) %>% imap(funx) %>% enframe %>% unnest
[1] "cyl"
[1] "disp"
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 cyl   0.248
2 disp  0.47 `

Comment: that part works yes... but then to rename the column names

Comment: `enframe` can take `name` and `value` as arguments, but i think it would not be dynamic.  So, you can use `mtcars %>% select(2, 3) %>% imap(funx) %>% enframe %>% unnest %>% rename_all(~ names(mtcars)[2:3])`

Comment: ah, no but my real output has output names "name", 'transformation', 'removed', 'unimodality', 'shapiro_score' and I only want to rename name to "parameter. 

I think the problem might be that the output up to unnest is a tibble and not a dataframe

Comment: If you want to rename only a subset of columns, use `rename_at` It would `%>% rename_at(vars('name'), ~ 'parameter')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, after getting feedback on the github post, with the new version we can now do this:

```
   mtcars %>%
      select(1:2) %>%
        summarise_all(funx)
```

Which was actually the exact same syntax as I started my problem with when posting this question, but at the time of the previous `dplyr` version, this was not possible yet. 
So, good work that the `dplyr` team has made the syntax more 'natural' I would say.